# Adding Question and My Answer from Facebook

Tags: discussion

Over on the Facebook group: Genetic Genealogy Tips & Techniques, I just answered what I thought was an excellent question with (what I also thought) was a very good answer.

Is it proper, or allowed, to copy that person's question to G&FH (giving credit to the source of the question and the person who posed it) and then pasting my own response as an answer?

The reason why I want to do this is that on Facebook, this Q&A will get lost in the sea of Facebookness and will be forgotten, and I know I will never be able to find it again. Here at Genealogy Q&A, the question will be made available forever, by tags or searchable and I won't lose it, and other people here will benefit from it.

So which of these possibilities would and would not be allowed?

1. I post the question and answer, not giving credit for the source of the question.
2. I post the question and answer, giving credit for the source of the question and who posed it.
3. I post the question and answer, giving credit for the source of the question and who posed it after asking the Facebook poster for permission to post it here.
4. I ask the original poster to join our group here and post the question herself and then I add my answer. The trouble with this is, of course, I would think there is a good possibility that the original poster has no interest in doing this.

Comment: Good question but I don't have an answer other than that I'm uneasy posting the Facebook question here even with attribution, at least not without the OP's permission.  Can you construct a similar 'case study'?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a similar case study for this.

Comment: Can you create a generic question that illustrates the same problem?

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl: Not really. If you're a member of the Facebook group, I can give you a link here to the question and my answer.

Comment: I don't Facebook. Sorry

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl - I didn't either until a couple of years ago - but there are some great genealogy groups led by leaders in their field with huge participation and great content that are not to be missed.

Answer (score 5):

[Genetic Genealogy Tips & Techniques](https://www.facebook.com/groups/geneticgenealogytipsandtechniques/?ref=br_rs) is a Closed Group on Facebook.  According to the Help Center's FAQ [What are the privacy settings for groups?](https://www.facebook.com/help/220336891328465?helpref=about_content), only current members of a group can see the content of the group, even when it is shared outside the group.

I admin some closed groups on Facebook. The context is a mix of news items and personal postings.  For ordinary news items, I might share those in the groups and on Twitter -- but for the personal postings, there is an *expectation* that the information doesn't go beyond the group.  That was the whole point of making the groups closed -- that the members' participation won't be broadcast in their News Feed on Facebook.

The National Genealogical Society offers some guidelines as a PDF download:
[Guidelines for Sharing Information With Others Recommended By the National Genealogical Society](https://www.ngsgenealogy.org/wp-content/uploads/NGS-Guidelines/Guidelines_SharingInfo2016-FINAL-30Sep2018.pdf). They suggest that

> genealogists and family historians respect the restrictions on sharing information that arise from the rights of another as an author, originator, or compiler; as a living private person; or a as party to a mutual agreement

If something wasn't meant to be widely shared on Facebook, then it seems reasonable to assume that it shouldn't be shared outside Facebook either.

I would say that only options three and four -- posting the question **with the permission of the original poster**, or inviting them to post here so you can share your answer, are acceptable.

Whatever you decide to do, I would recommend making a copy of the question and answer for your personal archive.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.